# Connect to Cloud SQL Private Postgres instance from outside

Tags: postgresql, docker, service-accounts, cloud-sql-proxy

The Postgres instance does not have a public IP and is using a VPC network. To reach it I am using the cloud sql docker proxy on OSX and a service account with the cloud sql admin role and cloud sql API enabled.

I am able to start the proxy and request a connection to the instance:

```
$ Listening on 0.0.0.0:5432 for myproject:northamerica-northeast1:myproject-database-someid
$ Ready for new connections
$ New connection for "myproject:northamerica-northeast1:myproject-database-someid"
```

The request eventually times out as it is refused:

```
$ couldn't connect to "myproject:northamerica-northeast1:myproject-database-someid": dial tcp 192.168.0.3:3307: connect: connection refused
```

However in the Postgres database logs I can see that the request was reached and authorized:

```
        { 
         ...,
         authorizationInfo: [
         0: {
          granted: true     
          permission: "cloudsql.instances.connect"     
          resource: "instances/myproject-database-someid"
          resourceAttributes: {}
         }
       ]
       methodName: "cloudsql.instances.connect"
```

I have tried applying firewall rules (open port 3307) on the VPC network to no avail.